# 50 error: invalid operands to binary % (have' int ' and ' *int ')

Tags: function, pointers

I get this error at line 50.I dont know what to use instead of (*p).  
 
I am learning how to use pointers and trying to use pointers in a function passing arguments by reference.
I've been staring at it for some time now.

```
# include "stdio.h"


int odd (int (*), int );

main(){

int i,n;
int size;

int main(){

int v[i];
int *p;
p = &v[0];

printf("Write the quantity of integers you want to ingress");
scanf("%d",&size);
for(i=0;i<size;i++){

        printf("write a number");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        v[i]= n;
        p = &v[i];

     odd(&v[i],size);


    printf("The value number %d is: %d \n",i,*p);

                     }

    return 0;



    }

    int odd(int *p,int siz){

        int i;
        int counter = 0;



        for(i=0;i<siz;i++){

      /*50*/      if(*p % 2 = 0){  }
                  else counter++  ;

    return counter;
        }


                     }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing assignment (`=`) with testing for equality (`==`). Change:

```
if(*p % 2 = 0)
```

to:

```
if(*p % 2 == 0)
```

Also your prototype for `odd` is wrong - change:

```
int odd (int (*), int );
```

to:

```
int odd (int *, int );
```